# "Stereo Mix" produces very distorted, near to unrecognizable output

Tags: windows, drivers, audio-recording

I'm on Windows 8 RTM x64, using the [designated Realtek Drivers](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3907#dl).

Sample: http://puu.sh/1HVew/a12007f54a01896920b954c792fe991b (Yes, this was once music)

This is not just random noise, the output is almost silent when no sound is played. This recording was done with Audacity, although I got the same issue with "Listen to this device" (+ unbearable feedback)

Comment: I understand you are recording with Audacity, but what are you playing from (Windows Media Player/Browser/WinAmp etc)?

Comment: Various. Skype, iTunes, Winamp.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=25281) pertain to your problem ? You could also try older versions of Realtek Drivers.

Comment: Is this a laptop. Do you have a microphone, internal or external?

Comment: Desktop, USB mic. Also using line-in. Have tried to disable all those, no change.

Comment: The main issue was a lack of drivers for Windows 8, Realtek has since addressed the issue and released drivers that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your sound and graphic and chipset drivers are up to date.

Also, what format are you recording in, as I would assume it's attempting in something your sound card can't handle (such as 24 bit 96khz). Try recording in 16bit at 44.1 and see if that helps.

It could be your machine just struggling if it is not powerful enough.

Try using the Windows sound recorder and see if the problem persists.

Also, check how many output devices you have. If more than one try disabling all but one.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, mute all playback and recording devices you aren't using (mic, line in etc.). Perhaps the interference comes from one of these inputs.

Comment: I did try that, and it didn't work. I suppose it's because I switched to Windows 8, because it was just working fine before.